# Why MikTeX updates its binaries so often?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I used to update MiKTeX regularly, might be because the update procedure is fast, convenient and easy [in contrast to TeX Live]. However I wonder why MiKTeX author publishes updated versions of executable files [usually about 90 units] so often. For example, previous update was dated by April 20 and the very last one by May 12. As I see it, TeX core is very stable. So what is the reason of so frequent updates?

Comment: I think a recent update to the binaries was for https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/510. The binaries do not only contain the 'TeX core' (which is largely unchanged), they also contain additional ancillary stuff. That said, LuaTeX for example was very actively changed up until a while ago (it is supposed to be stable now, but still gets bug fixes). From time to time new code is added to the engines, see for example (e.g. recently `\expanded`) https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-700009

Comment: With TeX live many big changes are only applied for a new release, so you won't notice binary changes because you are installing a new system anyway. But just a few days ago LuaTeX got better non-ASCII filename support on Windows: See the thread https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-April/045485.html on the TeX live mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the MikTeX source code repository (it was my attempt to compile it with clang in Windows). I might have an answer. It's my opinion based on decades of software engineering experience.

MikTeX source code imports the source code of hundreds of other projects. Then the maintainer manually modifies them all to make them work within MikTeX. The amount of work is staggering. The number of only `CMakeLists.txt` files written manually is 238. It means that the number of other files required modification probably counts to thousands. When you do so much manual modification, you with 100% certainty introduce new bugs and problems. For example, *in Windows MikTex's `LuaLaTeX` is an order of magnitude slower than TexLive's one*. In Linux a fresh installation of MikTeX has problems with language packages. There is a bug in the in-memory list of packages, sometimes it is empty and MikTeX refuses to download packages automatically. These bugs will never be addressed, because the maintainer doesn't have time and resources to reproduce them, save to fix.

Considering MikTeX has just one maintainer, the answer is there are constantly so many major problems, the author must issue updates often to fix them.

From the software design perspective MikTeX shoots itself in the leg (actually both and even somewhat higher) with a powerful machine gun. It's a self-inflicted maintenance nightmare that doesn't leave a room to implement improvements and fix bugs.

After looking at the MikTeX's source code, I switched to TeXLive both in Linux and Windows and now enjoying live (pun intended). In Linux TexLive's LuaLaTeX chewing pages with rocket speed, 13s for 100 pages on my laptop.